# Using the Programming Language C to test the pins of Arduino Board

Tags: c, arduino

I'm a student and im currently learning the basics of microprocessors.

I've been assigned a task with no prior knowledge of the task itself and i've been struggling to find the answer to it. So i wanted to give it a shot on Stackoverflow.

The task is to write a simple program using the Programing language C to test the Arduino board which first initializes the 12th pin and afterwards continually gives pin 5V for 5 seconds and a low voltage in 0 for 1 seconds for the same pin.

For a humble solution or explanation for it i would be very happy.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

Im referring to the Arduino Hardware.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand, more specifically? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to code in C language and technically i don't understand the whole question itself.

Comment: How to test a specific pin in this case the 12th and use send a specific amount of voltage to that for a specific amount of time

Comment: Well, if you don't know C then it's pretty much mission impossible, unless you wish to write the code in assembler.

Comment: well the first step would obviously be to ask the person who gave you the task. that's what he's being paid for. Arduino is usuall programmed in C++, not C btw. so are you referring to the Arduino hardware or the whole Arduino ecosystem including the IDE?

Comment: The task is to use C language, which as you said yourself is mission impossible for me.

Comment: I'm referring to the Arduino hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the task is to set a certain pin as output, the first thing you need to do is to check the board schematics to find out which microcontroller port and pin that "pin 12" corresponds to. Microcontroller ports often have a 1 letter name such as PORTA, PORTB etc. This is also the case for AVR.

Once you have found out which port that's the correct one, you also have to figure out which bit in that port register to set. There will be 8 pins per port, since each port on this MCU corresponds to 8 bit registers.

Since you want this pin to be an output, you have to configure a "data direction register" to make it such. On AVR (and most Motorola-flavoured MCUs), these registers are called DDRx, where x is the port letter. See the AVR manual, GPIO section. You set the DDR register as output by writing a one to the bit corresponding to the pin.

Once that is done, you can set the relevant bit in actual port register to 1 or 0, depending on if you want a high or low signal. These are called PORTx on AVR.

To create a 5 second delay, it is likely enough for hobbyist/student purposes to call a "busy wait" function. The Arduino libs has the `delay()` function that should suffice. Simply wait 5000ms. In professional/real-world applications, busy-wait delays should be avoided and then you'd rather use the on-chip hardware peripheral timers instead, to set a flag when the timer has elapsed.

Comment: The answer covered some points, i used to work on the answer myself. The solution to my task was rather simple though i made it look more difficult than it actually was. Don't feel obliged to answer a question if you think it is a waste of your time. Though i appreciate your input. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

From your post I take that you have an Arduino board.

It is unlikely that someone told you to program it in C as you don't know any C. And programming that Arduino's AVR microcontroller bare metal in C is impossible of someone of your skill level.

So let's assume you're supposed to complete the indeed very simple task of programming an Arduino with the Arduino IDE in C++ to do what is asked.

All you have to do is follow this link:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide

I won't give you any code as this would take away the learning experience from you.

You will have to configure pin 12 as a digital output.
You will have to find out how to set LOW and HIGH to a digital output
You will find out how to pause/delay your program for a number of seconds.

Comment: To be more precise, this is rather a question i had in an exam. The professor doesn't lecture the subject anymore since it has been removed from the curriculum and after a long history of email, i have been left with no answers. Regardless, the question itself is rather complicated and i cannot simplify it myself since i have no prior knowledge to do so. 
The question is to test an Arduino Board using the Language C and nor do i have the board to play around with and also i dont possess any knowledge in the C whatsoever.

Comment: @Piglet. maybe Lundin is the mentioned professor :-)